# How to create a popunder code or how it works

Tags: javascript

Actually I was trying to create a popunder code but it's not working correctly so searched for quite a while on online. But no luck. Here's an example from past.

```
function makePopunder(pUrl) {
var _parent = (top != self && typeof (top["document"]["location"].toString()) === "string") ? top : self;
var mypopunder = null;
var pName = (Math["floor"]((Math["random"]() * 1000) + 1));
var pWidth = window["innerWidth"];
var pHeight = window["innerHeight"];
var pPosX = window["screenX"];
var pPosY = window["screenY"];
var pWait = 3600;
pWait = (pWait * 1000);
var pCap = 50000;
var todayPops = 0;
var cookie = "_.mypopunder";
var browser = function () {
    var n = navigator["userAgent"]["toLowerCase"]();
    var b = {
        webkit: /webkit/ ["test"](n),
        mozilla: (/mozilla/ ["test"](n)) && (!/(compatible|webkit)/ ["test"](n)),
        chrome: /chrome/ ["test"](n),
        msie: (/msie/ ["test"](n)) && (!/opera/ ["test"](n)),
        firefox: /firefox/ ["test"](n),
        safari: (/safari/ ["test"](n) && !(/chrome/ ["test"](n))),
        opera: /opera/ ["test"](n)
    };
    b["version"] = (b["safari"]) ? (n["match"](/.+(?:ri)[\\/: ]([\\d.]+)/) || [])[1] : (n["match"](/.+(?:ox|me|ra|ie)[\\/: ]([\\d.]+)/) || [])[1];
    return b;
}();

function isCapped() {
    try {
        todayPops = Math["floor"](document["cookie"]["split"](cookie + "Cap=")[1]["split"](";")[0]);
    } catch (err) {};
    return (pCap <= todayPops || document["cookie"]["indexOf"](cookie + "=") !== -1);
};

function doPopunder(pUrl, pName, pWidth, pHeight, pPosX, pPosY) {
    if (isCapped()) {
        return;
    };
    var sOptions = "toolbar=no,scrollbars=yes,location=yes,statusbar=yes,menubar=no,resizable=1,width=" + pWidth.toString() + ",height=" + pHeight.toString() + ",screenX=" + pPosX + ",screenY=" + pPosY;
    document["onclick"] = function (e) {
        if (isCapped() || window["pop_clicked"] == 1 || pop_isRightButtonClicked(e)) {
            //return;
        };
        window["pop_clicked"] = 1;
        mypopunder = _parent["window"]["open"](pUrl, pName, sOptions);
        if (mypopunder) {
            var now = new Date();
            document["cookie"] = cookie + "=1;expires=" + new Date(now["setTime"](now["getTime"]() + pWait))["toGMTString"]() + ";path=/";
            now = new Date();
            document["cookie"] = cookie + "Cap=" + (todayPops + 1) + ";expires=" + new Date(now["setTime"](now["getTime"]() + (84600 * 1000)))["toGMTString"]() + ";path=/";
            pop2under();
        };
    };
};

function pop2under() {
    try {
        mypopunder["blur"]();
        mypopunder["opener"]["window"]["focus"]();
        window["self"]["window"]["blur"]();
        window["focus"]();
        if (browser["firefox"]) {
            openCloseWindow();
        };
        if (browser["webkit"]) {
            openCloseTab();
        };
    } catch (e) {};
};

function openCloseWindow() {
    var ghost = window["open"]("about:blank");
    ghost["focus"]();
    ghost["close"]();
};

function openCloseTab() {
    var ghost = document["createElement"]("a");
    ghost["href"] = "about:blank";
    ghost["target"] = "PopHelper";
    document["getElementsByTagName"]("body")[0]["appendChild"](ghost);
    ghost["parentNode"]["removeChild"](ghost);
    var clk = document["createEvent"]("MouseEvents");
    clk["initMouseEvent"]("click", true, true, window, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, true, false, false, true, 0, null);
    ghost["dispatchEvent"](clk);
    window["open"]("about:blank", "PopHelper")["close"]();
};

function pop_isRightButtonClicked(e) {
    var rightclick = false;
    e = e || window["event"];
    if (e["which"]) {
        rightclick = (e["which"] == 3);
    } else {
        if (e["button"]) {
            rightclick = (e["button"] == 2);
        };
    };
    return rightclick;
};
if (isCapped()) {
    return;
} else {
    doPopunder(pUrl, pName, pWidth, pHeight, pPosX, pPosY);
};
```

}

makePopunder("http://www.yourdomain.com/");

I actually wanted to make something similar to this site : http://popunderjs.com/

you can check the demo here it's kind of amazing : http://code.ptcong.com/demos/bjp/demo.html

Comment: **define: popunder** - A variation on the pop-up window is the pop-under advertisement, which opens a new browser window hidden under the active window. Pop-unders do not interrupt the user immediately and are not seen until the covering window is closed, making it more difficult to determine which web site opened them. GO DIE IN A FIRE

Comment: lol nice btw, though that's not what I want to know. What I wanted is how to create one.

Comment: Seriously? You couldn't work out from the last 5 words of my comment that I understood that?